# Textverständnis: Heino – Wie ein Vogel im Wind

Tags: lyrics, listening-comprehension

[Heino – Wie ein Vogel im Wind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycnyYqm0iMM) (auch [hier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BK_YUa6K1A)):

Ich höre dieses Lied und versuche, den Wortlaut vollständig zu verstehen.
Dabei bin ich schon weit gekommen, aber einige Passagen erschließen sich mir nicht (s. meine Transkription).

Leider konnte ich den Liedtext auch nicht per Suchmaschine oder auf *lyric sites* finden.

Könnte mir jemand die Stellen aufschreiben, die in meiner Transkription fehlen?

> hoch am Himmel kann ich ihn seh'n
>   manchmal will ich gern mit ihm zieh'n
>   in Gedanken die ganze Welt von dort oben seh'n
>   ja! Das wäre schön
>   |> den Äquator, das ewige Eis
>   die hohen Berge und das Edelweiss
>   das Erwachen des Frühlings, das Leuchten des Abendglüh'ns
>   ei, das könnte ich sehen
>   ja! Das wäre schoen <|
>   wie ein Vogel im Wind
>   schwerelos und ohne Sorgen
>   ein Gefühl so schön und klar
>   wie ein neuer Morgen
>   wie ein Vogel im Wind
>   durch die Lüfte schweben
>   ein Gefühl so schön und klar
>   mein Traum wird wahr
>   hoch am Himmel kann ich ihn seh'n
>   wie er stolz da oben schwebt
>   sein Gefieder (???) leicht, hell, blau, gruen, und weiss
>   denn er die Wolken erreicht
>   frueh am Abend (???) er dann flieht
>   (???) eine sanfte Melodie
>   Die so froh ist und so (???)
>   Die nach Freiheit spricht
>   (???)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the lyrics that can be found online using standard search engines? (Like here: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lyrics+Heino+wie+ein+Vogel+im+Wind&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: @Philipp That was my first idea, too. But did you actually find the lyrics? All results I clicked had effectively no lyrics in them. So I think, they are probably actually nowhere on the internet yet. Else they would show up in the top results, I guess.

Comment: @Confused_Yank The youtube video you linked cannot be viewed from Germany (I guess, because of intellectual property rights). Is it the same song as under https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BK_YUa6K1A ?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast This question is about listening comprehension. Please name a website which has the lyrics, instead of giving a general reference to a search engine. I used a search engine and was unable to find the lyrics (as I wrote above already).

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach You were right, the lyrics don't seem to be on among the first couple of search hits. I haven't looked any further.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Currently there is a [Meta-discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/are-comments-requesting-a-google-search-welcome?cb=1) regarding comments that request using search engines. (Just in case, you haven't noticed and want to join the discussion)

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. The closing votes did not substantiate the claim that the lyrics could (easily) be found somewhere else on the internet. The question is about listening comprehension, so neither about _proofreading, spell checking_ nor _translations of individual texts_, as the closing votes claim. And I do not know, which other place the questioner could get their information from. I think, we should answer those questions here on german.se This is backed by the fact that we even have a tag _listening comprehension_.

Comment: Related Meta post: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/are-question-on-the-meaning-of-spoken-dialogues-on-topic

Comment: Why are there so many assuming that I hadn't attempted to look for the lyrics on Google before asking for help here? :)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Would you like to reconsider your decision to vote for closing in the light of the discussion? If not, could you please make a case which does not rely on the (wrong) assumption, the lyrics would be easily findable elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to view the video you linked. So I transcribed the song at youtube.com/watch?v=-BK_YUa6K1A Looks, as if it is the same song.

```
1.
Hoch am Himmel kann ich ihn seh'n.
Manchmal würd ich gern mit ihm zieh'n.
In Gedanken die ganze Welt von dort oben seh'n, 
ja das wäre schön!

Den Äquator, das ewige Eis,
Die hohen Berge und das Edelweiß,
Das Erwachen des Frühlings,
Das Leuchten des Alpenglüh'ns,
All das könnte ich seh'n.

Den Äquator, das ewige Eis,
Die hohen Berge und das Edelweiß,
Das Erwachen des Frühlings,
Das Leuchten des Alpenglüh'ns,
All das könnte ich seh'n.

Ja, das wäre schön.

(Refrain)
Wie ein Vogel im Wind,
Schwerelos und ohne Sorgen
Ein Gefühl so schön und klar,
Wie ein neuer Morgen.

Wie ein Vogel im Wind
Durch die Lüfte schweben,
Ein Gefühl, so schön und klar -
Ein Traum wird wahr!

2. 
Hoch am Himmel kann ich ihn seh'n,
Wie er stolz da oben schwebt,
Sein Gefieder schimmert leicht 
Hellblau, grün und weiß,
Wenn er die Wolken erreicht.

Früh am Abend, wenn er dann fliegt
Hör ich eine zarte Melodie,
Die so froh ist und so beschwingt,
Die nach Freiheit klingt.
Ja, die mit mir singt!
Ja, die mir mir klingt!

(Refrain)
Wie ein Vogel im Wind,
Schwerelos und ohne Sorgen
Ein Gefühl so schön und klar,
Wie ein neuer Morgen.

Wie ein Vogel im Wind
Durch die Lüfte schweben,
Ein Gefühl, so schön und klar -
Ein Traum wird wahr!

Ein Gefühl, so schön und klar -
Ein Traum wird wahr!
```

Comment: Warum wird mir beim Lesen zu gruselig leer im Hirn?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Weil Heino nicht deinem Geschmack entspricht.

Comment: Hm. Ich hätte eher auf Argumente auf Textebene gehofft.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Der Text enthält nicht viel Aussage. Lediglich eine Sehnsucht nach der wohl verklärten Freiheit eines Vogels ist zu finden. Ohne ein konkretes Beispiel dafür zu geben, viele Pop-Texte sind nicht viel besser. Wenn sie fremdsprachig sind, merkt man es halt nicht immer.

Comment: Thank you so much jonathan.scholbach! Indeed, personally, I find learning German by listening to music the best way to progress and to keep your knowledge of it from getting rusty. This is a listening comprehension question. I don't know why so many people are so upset about it. :(. I know these songs may sound corny to the native ears but to me, they are simply beautiful and can teach me so much about German culture!